# What's the meaning of [socket:number] in /proc/pid/fd

Tags: linux, proc, socket

UNIX domain sockets opened by given `$PID` are listed in `/proc/$PID/fd/X` as symlinks to `[socket:ID]`. I understand that it's an identifier of that socket, but what exactly is it? Is it an inode in `sockfs`? Is it an inode at all?

```
# stat  /proc/15474/fd/18
  File: /proc/15474/fd/18 -> socket:[100754490]
  Size: 64              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
Device: 4h/4d   Inode: 100753577   Links: 1
Access: (0700/lrwx------)  Uid: (  999/mysql)   Gid: (  999/  docker)
Access: 2020-08-14 10:08:09.834593933 +0200
Modify: 2020-08-14 10:08:07.842537799 +0200
Change: 2020-08-14 10:08:07.842537799 +0200
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is indeed the inode number of the specific socket.

There are good answers on these Unix & Linux SE posts:

1. [/proc/PID/fd/X link number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10050/310662)
2. [What characterizes a file in Linux/Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500907/310662)

(Please note that I couldn't post this as a comment due to reputation restrictions, hope it is still useful)

Comment: BTW: this is Linux.... on a real procfs-II, these files are of the basic underlying file type, so `/proc/15474/fd/18` is a socket and not a symlink.